# html img tag with svg looks smaller when html is received from server and larger when I open html from file-system

Tags: html, css, image, svg, png

When I open the following html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>SVG</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <img width="32px" height="32px" src="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/android.svg" alt="Kiwi standing on oval"/>
</body>
```

By double clicking the html file on my file system, it opens chrome and shows the svg image properly. 
When the exact same html file is received from my node server, the image is displayed smaller (looks like its scaled down):
[image: svg diff]

I have looked at the html, body properties using chrome dev tools but I cant find the reason why this happening. The reason it bothers me is that when I instead use png files I get the same problem and the images are blurry and don't look the same when open in photoshop. 
Thanks

Comment: Is a browser window scale in effect?  Try doing `Ctrl-0` (zero) on each window.  Window scaling is remembered on a per-domain basis.

Comment: Thanks. That was the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding svg tag instead of img tag.

```
<svg width="32" height="32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 96 105">
  <g fill="#97C024" stroke="#97C024" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round">
    <path d="M14,40v24M81,40v24M38,68v24M57,68v24M28,42v31h39v-31z" stroke-width="12"/>
    <path d="M32,5l5,10M64,5l-6,10 " stroke-width="2"/>
  </g>
  <path d="M22,35h51v10h-51zM22,33c0-31,51-31,51,0" fill="#97C024"/>
  <g fill="#FFF">
    <circle cx="36" cy="22" r="2"/>
    <circle cx="59" cy="22" r="2"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>SVG</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <svg width="32" height="32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 96 105">
  <g fill="#97C024" stroke="#97C024" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round">
    <path d="M14,40v24M81,40v24M38,68v24M57,68v24M28,42v31h39v-31z" stroke-width="12"/>
    <path d="M32,5l5,10M64,5l-6,10 " stroke-width="2"/>
  </g>
  <path d="M22,35h51v10h-51zM22,33c0-31,51-31,51,0" fill="#97C024"/>
  <g fill="#FFF">
    <circle cx="36" cy="22" r="2"/>
    <circle cx="59" cy="22" r="2"/>
  </g>
</svg>
</body>
```